# Как для Selenium указать директорию с пррофайлом, чтобы при последующей загружке браузер бы использовал кэш?

Tags: python, selenium

Такой код на питоне у меня не работает:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/path/to/ff_profile')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Браузер по прежнему использует для кеша какую-то другую директорию:

```
disk
Number of entries:  88
Maximum storage size:   358400 KiB
Storage in use:     1758 KiB
Storage disk location:  /var/folders/jj/rdpd1ww53n95y5vx8w618k3h0000gq/T/tmpy6zyksfi/webdriver-py-profilecopy/cache2
List Cache Entries
```

Для вышеуказанного пути `/path/to/ff_profile` я создал рабочую директорию через `firefox-bin -p`.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего проблема в следующем:

очень похоже что это относительный путь к директории профилей указанной в фаярфоксе.

Когда же ты работаешь в своей программе -- ты указываешь тот же относительный путь, но он уже идет относительно твоей программы. Помести категорию с профилем фаярфокса в папку с твоей программой или используй абсолютный путь к профилю.